# Magento success page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

This has to do with coming up with php for the google trusted store badge - specifically setting the estimated delivery date.

I have this code on my success page that prints the data:

```
<?php
$order_items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($order_items as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

    echo $product->getAttributeText('estdelivery'); //changed getAttributeText to getData
    echo '|';
}


 ?>
```

if there is more than one item in the order it will print the attribute data - in this case 6 and 7

as one item has 6 days set in the attribute the other item has 7 days set in the attribute

I need a way in php to only print the higher number i.e. 7

the code i am currently using in the badge is

```
<span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date"><?php echo $deliveryDate=Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days")); ?></span>
```

But I need it to find all the delivery date attributes of all the items and enter the larger number into that code for delivery date

updated so I am using this and it successfully returns the higher of the variables

```
<?php
$order_items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($order_items as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());



}

$a=array($product->getAttributeText('estdelivery'));
$c=0;
foreach($a as $b)
{
if($b>$c)
$c=$b;

}
echo $c;

 ?>
```

So how do i got from that to the code I am using for estimated delivery date?? will this work below?

```
<span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date"><?php echo $deliveryDate=Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$order_items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($order_items as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());



}

$a=array($product->getAttributeText('estdelivery'));
$c=0;
foreach($a as $b)
{
if($b>$c)
$c=$b;

}
echo $c;
 days")); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the issue correctly, it seems like this should fix it:

```
<?php 
    $order_items = $order->getAllItems();
    $maxDelivery = 0;
    foreach($order_items as $item) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        if ($product->getAttributeText('estdelivery') > $maxDelivery) { 
            $maxDelivery = $product->getAttributeText('estdelivery');
        }

    }
    echo $maxDelivery;
?>
```

Loop through the products and keep track of the largest estdelivery value seen, and print that.

Comment: thanks for the input I actually edited my question and have it printinng the higher value but will use your method instead looks m,ore up to date :)

Comment: so my question now is how do i translate that into    <span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date"><?php echo $deliveryDate=Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days")); ?></span>

Comment: "+($order_items = $order->getAllItems();
    $maxDelivery = 0;
    foreach($order_items as $item) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        if ($product->getAttributeText('estdelivery') > $maxDelivery) { 
            $maxDelivery = $product->getAttributeText('estdelivery');
        }

    }
    echo $maxDelivery;) days"

Comment: <span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date"><?php echo $deliveryDate=Date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days")); ?></span>  change ("+7 days") to  ("?????????") so close but still not figuring it out

Comment: He won't use your code now haha

Comment: His code works just fine and I will be using his but I don't know how to insert it into that span ID I need to take the out put of that number the max of the estimitated deliver days and add it to the current date and output it into that Google trusted store badge if we can get a answer to that a lot of people will find it useful I couldn't find anything anywhere except that tid bit I am using  but for folks like me that ship multiple items via different carriers I Ned a more precise date than the date of the order as each item in the order has different delivery dates depending on item